JSArray<dynamic>: type List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic> Flutter Dart
I am trying to output data from database using parsedFromJson and getDataFromDB future method but I am getting error and is not resolving. I am an experienced developer but new to flutter. I never spent this amount of time to resolve anything in other tech stacks before
class House_Effects {
  final String? ID;
  final String? Title;
  final DateTime? Date;
 

 House_Effects({required this.ID, required this.Title, required this.Date });

factory House_Effects .fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return House_Effects (
      ID: json['ID'].toString(),
      Title: json['Title'].toString(),
      Date: json['Date']
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
     data['ID'] = this.ID.toString();
    data['Title'] = this.Title;
     data['Date'] = this.Date;
    return data;
  }
}


  List<House_Effects > parsedFromJson(String responseBody)  {
    
   List<dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(responseBody);
    
    List<Map<String, dynamic>>? endParsed = [];
     for (int idx = 0; idx < jsonData.length; idx++)
     {
      
     final parsed =  (jsonDecode(responseBody)) as Map<String,dynamic>;  
     
       endParsed.add(parsed);     
     }    
     return   endParsed.map<House_Effects >((json) =>
                                              House_Effects.fromJson(json)).toList();  
  }
  



Future<List<House_Effects>> getDataFromDB() async {

 
     List<House_Effects>   listEffects = [];
   const String bUrl = 'http://17627.9.9.1:4008';
   final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('$bUrl/show'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
         
        listEffects = await parsedFromJson(response.body);   
    
  } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to getdata');
  };   
  return listEffects; 
 }
}


---JSArray:  type List is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic>
Flutter Dart
THE ERROR is mainly from final parsed =  (jsonDecode(responseBody)) as Map<String,dynamic>;

All suggested related questions did not work

you need use cast.
List<House_Effects> parsedFromJson(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed
      .map<House_Effects>((json) => House_Effects.fromJson(json))
      .toList();
}


Thank you. But I am getting same error despite using your cast<Map<String,dynamic>> on same line. I think I did it like that originally. Thanks very much

my text was wrong, both "as" and "cast" to throw errors because jsonDecode(responseBody) returns a list of maps, not a single map. I corrected more things but was very brief, sorry :) I provided you with the complete function that works correctly, try it and you will see. Using cast prevents you from getting an error when converting and allows you to handle the error at the moment of accessing the value, preventing the app from crashing. I corrected the redundant call to jsonDecode, used .map to convert and toList() to return the list of House_Effects.

Also, there is no need to use await for parsedFromJson as it does not return a fucture.

List<House_Effects> parsedFromJson(String responseBody) {
final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
return parsed
.map<House_Effects>((json) => House_Effects.fromJson(json))
.toList();
}  did not work. Yes, no await.

did not work. Yes, no await. And even I did not really use for loop initially. So with or without for loop still did not work. My actual code in the repos b4 I started making some modifications to force out data which I still did but with still same error (but still bad output) was from: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/background-parsing ==> so it exactly same as yours and also there was no await. I did not change my above modified code b4 posting since exactly same error from exactly same one line of code.

So i still need that line (original from flutter.dev for exact similar situation) modified or I categorize it a google flutter bug. Thank you v much

ok, you're welcome. :)
